# select records which do not have a specific flag Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table in this format:

```
orgkey preferred_flg phonenumber
00111    N          1234566
00111    N          3436456
00111    Y          2388458
00222    N          6634634
00222    N          8834878
00222    N          0034090
00222    N          2736276
```

I am attempting to get the orgkey which do not have any record with Preferred Flg as Y. For example, from the above sample, I should get `00222` because that orgkey do not have any record with preferred_flg as Y.

I have tried this but it will not give me a `count(*)` of 0:

```
select orgkey, count(*)
from phone_table
where preffered_flg != 'Y'
group by orgkey
having count(*) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to find orgkeys that do not have a Y preffered_flg:

```
select distinct orgkey
from phone_table p1
where not exists (select 1 from phone_table p2
                  where p1.orgkey = p2.orgkey
                    and p2.preffered_flg = 'Y')
```